# Criteria Builder returning different kind of object with a count generated value for a column?

Tags: jpql, query-builder, criteria-api

I am facing this difficult.

I have this method:

public List findEmployees(String name) {

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Employee> c = cb.createQuery(Employee.class);
    Root<Employee> emp = c.from(Employee.class);
    c.select(emp);
    c.distinct(true);
    Join<Employee,Project> project =
        emp.join("projects", JoinType.LEFT);

    List<Predicate> criteria = new ArrayList<Predicate>();
    if (name != null) {
        ParameterExpression<String> p =
            cb.parameter(String.class, "name");
        criteria.add(cb.equal(emp.get("name"), p));
    }
    if (criteria.size() == 0) {
        throw new RuntimeException("no criteria");
    } else if (criteria.size() == 1) {
       c.where(criteria.get(0));
    } else {
        c.where(cb.and(criteria.toArray(new Predicate[0])));
    }

    TypedQuery<Employee> q = em.createQuery(c);
    if (name != null) { q.setParameter("name", name); }

    return q.getResultList();
}
```

Basically, here I am getting the Employee.

**What I want is** to have an object different than employee, employee is related with projects and I want to return an object `EmployeeProjectCount`

That is basically an object with:

id (from employee)
name (from employee)
numberProjects (is the count of the related projects to an employee)

Projects is a table with a column named "employee" that makes the relation.

I am wondering if at my criteria builder I can do that, a count of the related fields

Is it possible to return a different object?

I cannot do this:

```
TypedQuery<EmployeeProjectCount> q = em.createQuery(c);
```

my jpql query is like this:

```
select  e.id as id,  e.name as name, count(e) as total 
from 
Employee e
left join Project p on p.employee = e.id group by e;
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the `construct` method from `CriteriaBuilder`. It does exactly what you would otherwise use in jpql. You define the output class, and define the data that is used for it.
Here is a nice example of how to do this: [How to select a POJO with a Criteria Query](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/hibernate-tips-select-pojo-criteria-query/)